# Tic Tac Toe - Game always ending in a tie

Tags: python

I am having an issue with my Tic tic toe game.  After my first loop in def play_game the game is always ending in a tie.  I think it's is caused by my bool values in my check_for_tie function. I've tried playing with the values to no avail.  Bools always give me problems.

Additionally, if I remove the tie portion to test the if there is a winner it only breaks the loop after both players go.

```
# Global Variables
grid_values = [[" ", " ", " "],
               [" ", " ", " "],
               [" ", " ", " "]]
winner = None
game_still_going = True


def display_title():
    print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe")
    print()


def print_blank_board():
    print("+---+---+---+")
    print("|\t|\t|\t|")
    print("+---+---+---+")
    print("|\t|\t|\t|")
    print("+---+---+---+")
    print("|\t|\t|\t|")
    print("+---+---+---+")
    print()


# Function to test if the players move is a untaken spot
def grid_test(xcord, ycord, grid):
    if grid[xcord][ycord] == 1:
        print("Space is already taken.  Please select a different space:")
        return False
    elif grid[xcord][ycord] == 0:
        grid[xcord][ycord] = 1
        return True


# checks row for a winner
def check_rows():
    # Set global variables
    global game_still_going
    # Check if any of the rows have all the same value (and is not empty)
    row_1 = grid_values[0][0] == grid_values[0][1] == grid_values[0][2] != " "
    row_2 = grid_values[1][0] == grid_values[1][1] == grid_values[1][2] != " "
    row_3 = grid_values[2][0] == grid_values[2][1] == grid_values[2][2] != " "
    # If any row does have a match, flag that there is a win
    if row_1 or row_2 or row_3:
        game_still_going = False
    # Return the winner
    if row_1:
        return grid_values[0][0]
    elif row_2:
        return grid_values[0][0]
    elif row_3:
        return grid_values[0][0]
        # Or return None if there was no winner
    else:
        return None


# checks column for a winner
def check_columns():
    # Set global variables
    global game_still_going
    # Check if any of the rows have all the same value (and is not empty)
    column_1 = grid_values[0][0] == grid_values[1][0] == grid_values[2][0] != " "
    column_2 = grid_values[0][1] == grid_values[1][1] == grid_values[2][1] != " "
    column_3 = grid_values[0][2] == grid_values[1][2] == grid_values[2][2] != " "
    # If any row does have a match, flag that there is a win
    if column_1 or column_2 or column_3:
        game_still_going = False
    # Return the winner
    if column_1:
        return grid_values[0][0]
    elif column_2:
        return grid_values[0][1]
    elif column_3:
        return grid_values[0][2]
        # Or return None if there was no winner
    else:
        return None


# # checks diagonals for a winner
def check_diagonals():
    # Set global variables
    global game_still_going
    # Check if any of the rows have all the same value (and is not empty)
    diagonal_1 = grid_values[0][0] == grid_values[1][1] == grid_values[2][2] != " "
    diagonal_2 = grid_values[0][2] == grid_values[1][1] == grid_values[2][0] != " "
    # If any row does have a match, flag that there is a win
    if diagonal_1 or diagonal_2:
        game_still_going = False
    # Return the winner
    if diagonal_1:
        return grid_values[0][0]
    elif diagonal_2:
        return grid_values[0][1]
        # Or return None if there was no winner
    else:
        return None


# at the end of of the play_game loop it runs this function that calls 2 more functions to check if there is a winner or a tie
def check_if_game_over():
    check_for_winner()
    check_for_tie()


# checks for a winner and returns who won.
def check_for_winner():
    # Set global variables
    global winner
    # Check if there was a winner anywhere
    row_winner = check_rows()
    column_winner = check_columns()
    diagonal_winner = check_diagonals()
    # Get the winner
    if row_winner:
        winner = row_winner
    elif column_winner:
        winner = column_winner
    elif diagonal_winner:
        winner = diagonal_winner
    else:
        winner = None


# check if the game is a tie or not
def check_for_tie():
    global game_still_going
  # If board is full
    if " " not in grid_values:
        game_still_going = False
        return True
  # Else there is no tie
    else:
        return False


def play_game():
    turn = 1
    grid_tester = [[0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0]]
    test = False
    while game_still_going:
        #print("turn = ", turn)  #turn counter.  here just for testing.
        print("X's Turn")
        xtest = False
        otest = False
        # ASK user to select a row              FOR X
        while xtest == False:
            xrow = int(input("pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
            xrow += - 1
            while xrow < 0 or xrow >= 3:
                if xrow not in range(0 - 3):
                    print("Invalid option!!!")
                    xrow = int(input("pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
                    xrow += - 1

            # ASk user to select a column               FOR X
            xcolumn = int(input("pick a column (1, 2, 3): "))
            xcolumn += - 1
            while xcolumn < 0 or xcolumn >= 3:
                if xcolumn not in range(0 - 3):
                    print("Invalid option!!!")
                    xcolumn = int(input("pick a column (1, 2, 3): "))
                    xcolumn += - 1

            xtest = grid_test(xrow, xcolumn, grid_tester)
            if xtest == True:
                grid_values[xrow][xcolumn] = "X"
                turn += 1

        check_if_game_over()

        #turn += 1
        print()
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print("|", grid_values[0][0], "|", grid_values[0][1], "|", grid_values[0][2], "|")
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print("|", grid_values[1][0], "|", grid_values[1][1], "|", grid_values[1][2], "|")
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print("|", grid_values[2][0], "|", grid_values[2][1], "|", grid_values[2][2], "|")
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print()

        print("turn = ", turn)  ## here for testing.  REMOVE!!!!!!!
        print("O's Turn")


        # ASK user to select a row               FOR O

        while otest == False:
            orow = int(input("pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
            orow += - 1
            while orow < 0 or orow >= 3:
                if orow not in range(0 - 3):
                    print("Invalid option!!!")
                    orow = int(input("pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
                    orow += - 1

            # ASk user to select a column               FOR O
            ocolumn = int(input("pick a column (1, 2, 3): "))
            ocolumn += - 1
            while ocolumn < 0 or ocolumn >= 3:
                if ocolumn not in range(0 - 3):
                    print("Invalid option!!!")
                    ocolumn = int(input("pick a column (1, 2, 3): "))
                    ocolumn += - 1
            print(turn)  ## here for testing.  REMOVE!!!!!!!
            otest = grid_test(orow, ocolumn, grid_tester)
            if otest == True:
                grid_values[orow][ocolumn] = "O"
                turn += 1

        print()
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print("|", grid_values[0][0], "|", grid_values[0][1], "|", grid_values[0][2], "|")
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print("|", grid_values[1][0], "|", grid_values[1][1], "|", grid_values[1][2], "|")
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print("|", grid_values[2][0], "|", grid_values[2][1], "|", grid_values[2][2], "|")
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print()

        check_if_game_over()

    if winner == "X" or winner == "O":
        print(winner + " won.")
    elif winner is None:
        print("Game is a tie!")


def main():
    display_title()
    print_blank_board()
    play_game()

# if started as the main module, call the main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: A strange game.  The only winning move is not to play.

Comment: ^Not useful but great reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `check_for_tie` you can write:

**EDIT:**

```
global game_still_going
full_rows = 0
for i in range(3):
    if " " not in grid_values[i]:
        full_rows += 1
if full_rows == 3:
    game_still_going = False
    return True
else:
    return False
```

**ADD THIS**

```
if not game_still_going:
        break
```

after the first check_if_game_over() in the while

Comment: That partially fixed my problem.  I can now continue the game but after turn 6 it breaks in a tie.

Comment: I am sorry. What is should do is to check if there is any spaces left in the grid, what I did wrong was that if it finds a full row it stops. I will edit

Comment: Even though now it doesn't stop with a tie, even if I won using 'O' it shows that 'X' wins.

Comment: It's telling me who won correctly when I'm testing it.  The only 2 issues I am seeing is in the event the board is full it still wants to go 1 more turn and if X wins it won't end until O goes 1 more time